# JavaScript drawImage incorrectly crops the source canvas image on some computers

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a canvas on my page and I have an instrument which allows users to select an area, which he/she wants to crop. It looks like so:

[image]

To crop an image I calculate top-left pixel coordinate `[xmin, ymin]` and bottom-right coordinate `[xmax,ymax]`. And cropping itself is done like so:

```
context.drawImage(image,xmin,ymin,xmax-xmin,ymax-ymin,0,0,xmax-xmin,ymax-ymin);
```

And the problem is, on some random computers and some random browsers, this code produces correct chunk and on some others - incorrect. That is why I can not provide even a demo or a fiddle. Locally, on my laptop it's ok on all browsers (FF, IE, Opera, Chrome,Safari), but on my users computers it is incorrect.

So, my question is, what may be wrong with this call:

```
context.drawImage(image,xmin,ymin,xmax-xmin,ymax-ymin,0,0,xmax-xmin,ymax-ymin);
```

Is there something, I should take into account to make this code cross-browser and cross-platform?

Comment: By the way, the coordinates `[xmin, ymin]` and `[xmax,ymax]` are totally correct on all computers and in all browsers.

Comment: Blind shot since it's all we can do: **user zoom level** might be wrong. You need to ensure your image is rendered at the exact same size as its naturalWidth and height for your current code to work. Or make your values relative (i.e get the ratio of displayed image / natural + cursor position).

Comment: I get the image from Open Street Map and do not change its width or height somehow. So, it is rendered as it is without any zoom-in or zoom-out.

Comment: IIRC by default windows makes a +10% zoom everywhere. So I wouldn't be as sure as you are. This zoom would apply on the rendered content, and would make your Mouse coordinates wrong wrt the natural size of your image.  Simple to test though, take one of your browsers that does work, zoom in or out and check it still works.

Comment: Hm, you are right. I zoomed-in on my laptop in a working browser and it produced incorrect chunk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is* that some of your users have their browser's zoom-level set to something else than 100%.

With your current logic, you assume the image is displayed at its original size, which is the one used by `drawImage`. But when zoomed in or out, the browser does scale the rendered image, making the coordinates of the cursor wrong with regard to the natural size of your image.

To circumvent this, you need to scale your coordinates relatively to the ratio displayedSize / naturalSize.

Here is a simple example.

```js
onload = function() {
  const ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  c.width = img.width;
  c.height = img.height;

  img.onmousedown = c.onmousedown = handleMouseDown;
  img.onmousemove = c.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;
  img.onmouseup = c.onmouseup = handleMouseUp;
  
  var rect = { min_x: 0, min_y: 0, max_x: 0, max_y: 0, updating: false};
  
  draw();
  
  function handleMouseDown(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var targetBB = evt.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    rect.updating = true;
    rect.min_x = rect.max_x = evt.clientX - targetBB.left;
    rect.min_y = rect.max_y = evt.clientY - targetBB.top;
    draw();
  }
  function handleMouseUp(evt) {
    rect.updating = false;
    draw();
  }
  function handleMouseMove(evt) {
    if(!rect.updating) return;
    var targetBB = evt.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    rect.max_x = evt.clientX - targetBB.left;
    rect.max_y = evt.clientY - targetBB.top;
    draw();
  }
  function draw() {
    ctx.filter = 'blur(2px)';
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0);
    ctx.filter = 'none';
    var dx = Math.min(rect.min_x, rect.max_x),
      dy = Math.min(rect.min_y, rect.max_y),
      dw = Math.abs(rect.min_x - rect.max_x),
      dh = Math.abs(rect.min_y - rect.max_y);
    if(!dh || !dw) return;
    ctx.strokeRect(dx, dy, dw, dh);
    var ratio_W = img.clientWidth / img.naturalWidth,
      ratio_H = img.clientHeight / img.naturalHeight,
      sx = dx * ratio_W,
      sy = dy * ratio_H,
      sw = dw * ratio_W,
      sh = dh * ratio_H;
    ctx.drawImage(img, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh);
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>Try to zoom-in/out your browser</h3>
<img id="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujq5W.png">
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

*According to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48943270/#comment-84893386).

Comment: I checked it. For some reason, `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` properties are zero, while `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` are not null. But I also see `height` and `width` properties, which are also not null.

Comment: Oh, I can get it from canvas. It's ok.

Comment: @Jacobian yes I didn't know about your real use case, so now I'll understand you don't even show the <img> element, but just draw it on the canvas. In this case, simply get the clientWidth and clientHeight of the canvas instead of using the ones of the img.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it does not work. I ran multiple test and produced a working fiddle, which demonstrates this behaviour - http://jsfiddle.net/vicvolk/h9qb74Lg/99/ . Just start drawing a selection area on a map and on some cumputers and some browser you will get incorrect chunks - with or without scaling coordinates.

Comment: I made a new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48962400/unable-to-make-a-chunk-of-a-layer-in-openlayers. Probably, it has some relation to OpenLayers library. I'm not quite sure.