# Unable to make a chunk from canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, openlayers

I want to have such an interaction with a map, that when a user selects some area on the map, an image is created from this area. I made a minimized and compiltely reproducible example in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vicvolk/h9qb74Lg/99/). The most important part is this crop function:

```
function crop(img, sx, sy, dw, dh) {
   var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   canvas.width = dw;
   canvas.height = dh;
   ctx.drawImage(img, sx, sy, dw, dh, 0, 0, dw, dh);
   return canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}
```

This function creates a chunk out of selected area. This is how selection looks like:

[image]

But this is what I get as a result:

[image]

So, my chunk is totally incorrect. But what is more interesting is that on some arbitrary computers and in some arbitrary browsers chunks are correct. So, I really need to make this code cross-platform and cross-browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the problem is, it seems like from JavaScript code it is impossible to know this system/browser parameter - I mean initial page zoom level.

Actually there is [`window.devicePixelRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio)
Just use it in place of `ratio_W` and `ratio_H`, and it starts working:

```js
var initialZoom = devicePixelRatio;

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
  })],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-348792.96, 7170957.18],
    zoom: 10
  })
});

var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
   features: new ol.Collection(),
   type: "LineString",
   style: function (feature) {
       var style = [
         new ol.style.Style({
           fill: new ol.style.Fill({
             color: 'rgba(142,142,142,0.5)'
           }),
           stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
             color: 'rgba(142,142,142,1)',
             lineDash: [4,4],
             width: 2
           })
         })
       ];
       return style;
   },
   geometryFunction: function (coordinates, geom) {
       if (!geom) {
           geom = new ol.geom.Polygon(null);
       }
       var start = coordinates[0];
       var end = coordinates[1];
       var mapExtent = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());

       var chunk = [start, [start[0], end[1]], end, [end[0], start[1]],start];
       var coords = [[[mapExtent[0],mapExtent[1]],[mapExtent[0],mapExtent[3]],[mapExtent[2],mapExtent[3]],[mapExtent[2],mapExtent[1]],[mapExtent[0],mapExtent[1]]], chunk];
       map.exportExtent = coordinates; // all you need
       geom.setCoordinates(coords);
       return geom;
   },
   maxPoints: 2
});

var canvas = map.getViewport().firstChild;

draw.on("drawend", function (e) {
    var image = new Image(), 
        link = document.getElementById("export-png");
   
    var topLeft = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(map.exportExtent[0]);
    var bottomRight = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(map.exportExtent[1]);
    
    var sx = topLeft[0];
    var sy = topLeft[1];
    var dw = bottomRight[0] - topLeft[0];
    var dh = bottomRight[1] - topLeft[1];
    
    image.id = "pic";
    image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    image.onload = function () { 
        sx = sx * initialZoom;
        sy = sy * initialZoom;
        dw = dw * initialZoom;
        dh = dh * initialZoom;
        link.href = crop(image, sx, sy, dw, dh);
        link.click();
    };
    
    image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
});

map.addInteraction(draw);

function crop(img, sx, sy, dw, dh) {
   var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   canvas.width = dw;
   canvas.height = dh;
   ctx.drawImage(img, sx, sy, dw, dh, 0, 0, dw, dh);
   return canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}
```

```html
<link href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/build/ol-debug.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div> 
<a id="export-png" class="btn" download="map.png">&nbsp;</a>
```

Snippet comes from @dube's answer, and I modified `image.onload` <strike>only</strike> and stored `initialZoom` in the first line.

Comment: Thank you, sir! It looks promissing! I will check it tomorrow and accept the answer, if it's ok

Comment: @Jacobian I just added a snippet based on dube's (so it contains the fixes/simplifications they suggest)

Comment: I've just checked it. There is also some problem with this solution. Previous one worked when your default zoom level was 100%, and if you started to zoom-in (Ctrl+) or zoom-out (Ctrl-) it also worked. But if your default zoom level is not 100%, then it does not work. This new solution works even if default zoom level is not 100%, but it does not work if you Ctrl+ or Ctrl-. You can see it on demo. Just Ctrl+ and try to make a chunk.

Comment: @Jacobian yes, you are right, I briefly encountered that when tried the fiddle. A quick workaround has been added: ```devicePixelRatio``` is just stored as ```initialZoom``` at the beginning of execution, so subsequent changes do not distort it. I have a very strong feeling that the map component is doing exactly the same somewhere inside, and we have to work against that stored setting.

Comment: After saving the 30th map.png I think it works correctly now :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would have guessed that you mixed projections. But that was not the bug, you simply mixed up some variables. It's the unecessary complicated way of storing the selection extent.

`coordinate` of `geometryFunction` already has the extent, defined as two coordinates. Just use those and remove the loop. No idea why it's there in the first place.

```js
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
  })],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-348792.96, 7170957.18],
    zoom: 10
  })
});

var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
   features: new ol.Collection(),
   type: "LineString",
   style: function (feature) {
       var style = [
         new ol.style.Style({
           fill: new ol.style.Fill({
             color: 'rgba(142,142,142,0.5)'
           }),
           stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
             color: 'rgba(142,142,142,1)',
             lineDash: [4,4],
             width: 2
           })
         })
       ];
       return style;
   },
   geometryFunction: function (coordinates, geom) {
       if (!geom) {
           geom = new ol.geom.Polygon(null);
       }
       var start = coordinates[0];
       var end = coordinates[1];
       var mapExtent = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());

       var chunk = [start, [start[0], end[1]], end, [end[0], start[1]],start];
       var coords = [[[mapExtent[0],mapExtent[1]],[mapExtent[0],mapExtent[3]],[mapExtent[2],mapExtent[3]],[mapExtent[2],mapExtent[1]],[mapExtent[0],mapExtent[1]]], chunk];
       map.exportExtent = coordinates; // all you need
       geom.setCoordinates(coords);
       return geom;
   },
   maxPoints: 2
});

var canvas = map.getViewport().firstChild;

draw.on("drawend", function (e) {
    var image = new Image(), 
        link = document.getElementById("export-png");
   
    var topLeft = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(map.exportExtent[0]);
    var bottomRight = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(map.exportExtent[1]);
    
    var sx = topLeft[0];
    var sy = topLeft[1];
    var dw = bottomRight[0] - topLeft[0];
    var dh = bottomRight[1] - topLeft[1];
    
    image.id = "pic";
    image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    image.onload = function () { 
        var ratio_W = canvas.clientWidth / image.naturalWidth;
        var ratio_H = canvas.clientHeight / image.naturalHeight;
        //with or without scaling image chunk is incorrect
        sx = sx * ratio_W;
        sy = sy * ratio_H;
        dw = dw * ratio_W;
        dh = dh * ratio_H;
        // console.log(sx, sy, dw, dh, ratio_H);
        link.href = crop(image, sx, sy, dw, dh);
        link.click();
    };
    
    image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
});

map.addInteraction(draw);

function crop(img, sx, sy, dw, dh) {
   var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   canvas.width = dw;
   canvas.height = dh;
   ctx.drawImage(img, sx, sy, dw, dh, 0, 0, dw, dh);
   return canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}
```

```html
<link href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/build/ol-debug.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div> 
<a id="export-png" class="btn" download="map.png">&nbsp;</a>
```

Comment: Actually, I found what was the root cause of this bug - the initial zoom level in browser. You can easily reproduce the bug in the fiddle, that I provided, like so - go to this fiddle, then in your browser change page zoom level to 125% for example, then close the tab with the fiddle, then open it again and start making a chunk and you will see, that now you get an incorrect one. But the problem is, it seems like from JavaScript code it is impossible to know this system/browser parameter - I mean initial page zoom level.

Comment: By the way, this bug is reproduced in all browsers. So, it seems like if page zoom level is not 100% by default, then coordinate scaling (with `ratio_W` and `ratio_H`) does not work properly.

Comment: Wouldn't suprise me when zoom causes weird stuff with OL. However, your original code did/does have bugs, it did not work on normal zoom either.

Comment: In my case it worked good on default normal zoom, but stopped working if the initial zoom was not 100%.